# How to use apns gems in ruby on rails to send push notifications (rpush)

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, server-push

i m absolutely new to ruby on rails and while i was looking for a gem to use to send push notifications i came up with rpush.

i installed gems and made all the preparations but i can't seem to find a location to copy paste these codes or how to send a push ?

```
app = Rpush::Apns::App.new
app.name = "ios_app"
app.certificate = File.read("/path/to/sandbox.pem")
app.environment = "sandbox" # APNs environment.
app.password = "certificate password"
app.connections = 1
app.save!
n = Rpush::Apns::Notification.new
n.app = Rpush::Apns::App.find_by_name("ios_app")
n.device_token = "..."
n.alert = "hi mom!"
n.data = { foo: :bar }
n.save!
```

i edited the app name and located my .pem file but don't know where to paste these codes and how to send accutaly a push notification.

i tried to create a method in my controller but couldn't run it.

can someone lend me a hand

Comment: At what event (when) you want to send notification?

Comment: @RAJ... ill get input from user via a text_field and when user clicked submit button the notification should be sent 

but right now i  m getting this error
Validation failed: Name has already been taken

Extracted source (around line #26):
24
25
26
27
28
29
          
newApp.password = "pushchat"
newApp.connections = 1
newApp.save!  %>

Comment: your question is not related to this issue. Anyways it's validation error. It's saying you have same name already exists in db, try entering some other name

Comment: @RAJ... yea that was the first thing i tried, didn't help me

Comment: thn u should add another question for that showing related code like controller's action, model, view etc. Otherwise this question will loss it's potential

Answer (score 1):

you can create .rb file in /app/services folder. and add your method to write your push notification logic and call it from your model.